# Center a sphere in p5js when using shaders

Tags: shader, p5.js

I'm trying to center a sphere in the center of the canvas in p5js. I use shader language for this sketch and I can't figure it out where should I modify values for the coordinates of the sphere. That's how the js sketch looks:

```
let camShader;
let cam;

function preload() {
  camShader = loadShader("colorwave.vert", "colorwave.frag");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
  noStroke();

  cam = createCapture(VIDEO);
  cam.size(400, 400);

  cam.hide();
}

function draw() {
  shader(camShader);
  camShader.setUniform("tex0", cam);
  const mx = map(mouseX, 0, width, -0.5, 0.5);
  const my = map(mouseY, 0, height, -0.5, 0.5);
  camShader.setUniform("u_mouse", [mx, my]);
  camShader.setUniform("u_resolution", [width, height]);
  camShader.setUniform("u_time", millis() / 10000);
  //ellipse(260, 0, 200, 200, 100);
  sphere(16);
}
```

Comment: Sphere appears to be automatically centered on my system.